# Will replacing the rear shocks require a wheel alignment?

Tags: alignment, mazda-3, rear

About 2 months ago, I had a 4 wheel alignment done on my 2006 Mazda 3. Now I need to replace the rear shocks.

I'm planning on replacing the shocks myself and I am trying to avoid having to get another alignment done so soon.

How bad will the rear alignment be affected when replacing the shocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are shocks only and not struts on the back, it's a straight remove and replace operation on them. You will not need another wheel alignment with just a rear shock change. The only time you need a new alignment is when you mess with the geometry of the suspension. If you changed out ball joints, struts, tie rods, or the like.